# perl can't use undefined value as HASH reference

Tags: perl, hashmap

I am refactoring this script and I really do not understand the errors that I get.

```
#!/sbcd/GSD/scripts/perl/bin/perl
use DBI ;
use strict ;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
my $dbUser = 'foo_01';
my $dbPass = 'foo_01';
my $dbSid  = 'foo.WORLD';
my $dbh =  DBI->connect("dbi:Oracle:$dbSid","$dbUser","$dbPass") or die( "Couldn't connect: $!" );
my %extend_hash=%{@_[0]};
my @error_array=@{@_[1]};
my @queries_array=();
my %spec_hash=();
my $query = "select e_risk_symbol from gsd_etds where level_name='EXCH_CS' and e_exch_dest='XISX' and e_symbol_comment in ('Bin_6','Bin_56')";

if(!$dbh) { 
    print "Error connecting to DataBase; $DBI::errstr\n"; 
}
    my $cur_msg = $dbh->prepare($query) or die "\n\nCould not prepare statement: ".$dbh->errstr;
    $cur_msg->execute();
    while (my @row=$cur_msg->fetchrow_array) {
         $spec_hash{'XISX'}{$row[0]}=1;
     }
print Dumper(%spec_hash);
```

these are the errors: 
I especially do not understand the can't use an undefined values as a HASH reference

```
walt $ ./pure_extend_database
Scalar value @_[0] better written as $_[0] at ./pure_extend_database line 11.
Scalar value @_[1] better written as $_[1] at ./pure_extend_database line 12.
Can't use an undefined value as a HASH reference at ./pure_extend_database line 11.
```

This is what I get when I with the warning and strict ;

```
$VAR1 = 'XISX';
$VAR2 = {
          'FCEL' => 1,
          'GPS' => 1,
          'MCO' => 1,
          'DPZ' => 1,
          'WM' => 1,
          'SPLS' => 1,
          'ILMN' => 1,
          'BWLD' => 1,
          'CTSH' => 1,
          'EWU' => 1,
          'MDVN' => 1,
          'PDCO' => 1,
};
```

Comment: What is being passed to the script as arguments when you run it?

Comment: I have not gotten there - once I start passing arguments the errors/warning will go away?

Comment: Well normally the @_ array contains the arguments passed to a subroutine. Since this is not in a subroutine it is probably the reason for the error.  Try changing the @_ to @ARGV and then passing the correct arguments.

Comment: yes - really was wondering what it was - and it is the subroutine array.

Comment: This program has never compiled in the form you show so you are *not* refactoring it. Why don't you tell us where it came from and what you are trying to achieve? It really isn't worth trying to fix 24 lines of badly-written code: you should write something new that follows a specification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning you're getting is caused by attempting to dereference an undefined value as a hash. The dereferencing as a hash is done with the `%{ }`, and the undefined value is the empty array slice you took with `@_[0]` (although what you actually want when you retrieve a single element of an array is the `$` sigil, like the warnings tell you). The `@_` array is only useful inside of subroutines, where it contains the arguments that the subroutine is called with.

For an intro to references in Perl, see [`perldoc perlreftut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html).

For explanations on particular warnings, see [`perldoc perldiag`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html), or put [`use diagnostics;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/diagnostics.html) in your script to enable verbose warnings.

For the arguments given to the script on the command line, see `@ARGV` in [`perldoc perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) or `perldoc -v '@ARGV'`. This probably isn't what you want, however; the code you are refactoring appears to have had a subroutine you removed, and there's no way to pass hard references to the script from the command line.

Comment: excellent reverse engineering - this is part of a subroutine.

Comment: I commented out the my %extend_hash=%{@_[0]}; and the my @error_array=@{@_[1]}; and their  are not warnings.